# WPF: BusyIndicator when DataGrid loading and sorting

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid, busyindicator

I have a `DataGrid` with long time loading.
I want put a `BusyIndicator` for the time to wait.
I have declared a property "IsBusy" in my ViewModel, the BusyIndicator  is raised on it.
If I declare the property with "true" by default, the `BusyIndicator` does display `good => OK.`
If I declare it to be "false", the `BusyIndicator` is `hidden => OK.`

But, if I set the value by triggers in XAML, the property is well set, but the `BusyIndicator` doesn't appear.

ViewModel:

```
public bool IsBusy 
{ 
  get { return _IsBusy; }
  set { _IsBusy = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy)); } 
}
private void SetBusy(bool obj) 
{
    IsBusy = obj;
}
```

XAML:

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator Name="BusyBar" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" BusyContent="Traitement en cours. veuillez patienter..." />
<ComboBox x:Name="cbbSchEtt" ...>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetBusyCommand}" CommandParameter="True"/>
            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="LoadTableau" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ucTabBord}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

Same thing if I set it by code behind (m is my ViewModel):

```
private void LoadTableau() 
{
    m.IsBusy = true;//Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
    .....
    m.IsBusy = false;
}
```

For information, if I don't set it to false at the end of `LoadTableau()`, the `BusyIndicator` is displayed well.

Any idea ?

Comment: May you show us your SetBusyCommand?